# Integrate one regex into another one

Tags: regex

I have the following regex for validating a path in windows:

`^([A-Za-z]\:|\\|\.)(\\[^\\\/\:\*\?\""\<\>\|]*)+[\\]$`

This just works fine. The path must end with \

I have another regex that checks a given string if it is a so called macro-string. The syntax of a macro-string is:

- start with $
- ends with $
- may only contain [A-Za-z0-9] _ and :

Therefor I have the regex:

`[$][\w:]+(?:[$][\w:]+[$][\w:]+)*[$]`

Now I want to combine the two regular expression.

So that I can use a macro-string in a path-string.

The following path should be valid:

- C:\temp\$emittemppath$\

The following path is invalid:

- C:\temp\$emit()temppath$\

With just concat both regex with | the invalid-path would be recogniced as valid.

My question is also, how do I integrate the macro-regex in the other one. So that it checks the macro-syntax between $-chars?

---

Update:

A macro-name must be always between $

---

Update 2:

To identify which $ belongs to which part the \ could be used

Comment: It would help to specify which implementation/dialect of regex you are using, i.e. which tool/language, as they differ in what they'll accept.

Comment: I need it for a simple-type in xsd-validation

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=`to assert that it is a "macro-string":

`(?=.*[$][\w:]+(?:[$][\w:]+[$][\w:]+)*[$])`

If it is, then you could use add the part to validating a path in windows.

[`(?=.*[$][\w:]+(?:[$][\w:]+[$][\w:]+)*[$])^([A-Za-z]\:|\\|\.)(\\[^\\\/\:\*\?\""\<\>\|]*)+[\\]$`](https://regex101.com/r/3yWEQ8/1)

Comment: But with this regex the following path is recognised as valid:
`C:\temp\$emitte$\he$te()st$llo\`

Comment: I have combined your 2 regexes, and when adding `C:\temp\$emitte$\he$te()st$llo` to the [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/3yWEQ8/2) it will not be recognised as valid. What programming language are you using?

Comment: I also use the regex-tester. You have to paste every test-string one by one. In the tester if the first string machtes all other strings will not match.
see: https://regex101.com/r/3yWEQ8/3

Comment: You could enable the global regex flag for that. But I have not altered your regex logic. I am using "C:\temp\$emitte$\he$te()st$llo" which you mentioned and you are using "C:\temp\$emitte$\he$te()st$llo\"  which ends on a backslash. You state that "The path must end with \"

Comment: I mean 'C:\temp\$emitte$\he$te()st$llo\' This should not be valid. (Thanks for the tip with the global-flag) 
(Just recogniced that Stackoverflow removed my ending \

Comment: So you would like to match it [like this](https://regex101.com/r/v734I4/1) so that it would become [`(?=.*[$][\w:]+[$](?:[\w\\]+)?\\$)^([A-Za-z]\:|\\|\.)(\\[^\\\/\:\*\?\""\<\>\|]*)+[\\]$`](https://regex101.com/r/lprcIC/1/)

Comment: This looks very good. The only thing which fails is, that if I try 'C:\temp\test\' I don't get a match

Comment: Maybe [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/IzMOqy/1/) would match all the requirements.

Comment: It's close. I've added two examples where it also should match: https://regex101.com/r/IzMOqy/4